# Is there a JavaScript IDE that allows debugging in all three browsers (IE, FF, Chrome)?

Tags: javascript, web

I know WebStorm allows debugging in FF and Chrome, but I don't see IE support. Is there an IDE out there that can handle all 3?

Comment: I would also love to hear any answers..IE really sucks sometimes.. :)

Comment: Don't forget Safari and Opera :-)

Comment: By "debugging in FF and Chrome", what do you mean? Just launching a browser? Do you have interest in any particular IE version?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think anyone's covered all 3 browsers.

**Visual Studio** can debug IE.  It cannot debug FireFox or Chrome.
**WebStorm** can debug FireFox and Chrome (by installing extensions).

All browsers have their own debugging tools, too.  So you've got lots of options, but no silver bullet.